# Formik values don't update when I modifty it with .map() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have data in values from Formik library which is mapped, and each object of values(Formik) gets some data assigned to two properties.
When I console.log('valuesDeepcopy', valuesDeepcopy) it shows that data is properly assigned to pointed properties to the copy of each element, but when I console.log('values',values) I see that it's not updating Formik's value.

```
values.luxmeds.map((person) => {
    const filter = luxmedTypesPackages.filter((type) => {
      if (type.package === person.luxmedType.package && type.type === person.luxmedType.type)
        return true;
      return false;
    });
    if (!filter.length) return person;
    const valuesDeepcopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person));
    valuesDeepcopy.luxmedTypeId = filter[0]?.id;
    valuesDeepcopy.luxmedType.id = filter[0]?.id;

    console.log('valuesDeepcopy', valuesDeepcopy);
    console.log('filter', filter);
    return valuesDeepcopy;
  });
  console.log('values', values);
```

Can You please suggest what should be done make Formik's value update ?

thanks